# Store array keys in variable with foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When saving in an array the prices and ids of a product, with this code...

```
foreach($resource->group->tabs as $tab) {

                foreach($tab->articles as $article) 
                {
                    $prices_and_ids[] = array(
                        $article->article_erp_id => array(
                            'price_pvp'       => $article->price_pvp,
                            'price_promotion' => $article->price_promotion,
                        )
                    ); 
                }
            }
```

The result of **$prices_and_ids** with this code is an object with the keys numbered:

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    3140 => array:2 [▼
      "price_pvp" => 6.5
      "price_promotion" => 5.53
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    3141 => array:2 [▼
      "price_pvp" => 7.5
      "price_promotion" => 6.37
    ]
  ]
  2 ... ... ...
```

The result I want is that the article ids are the keys of the array.

**I want this:**

```
array:10 [▼
  3140 => array:1 [▼
      "price_pvp" => 6.5
      "price_promotion" => 5.53
  ]
  3141 => array:1 [▼
      "price_pvp" => 7.5
      "price_promotion" => 6.37
  ] ... ... ...
```

Comment: try this $prices_and_ids[$article->article_erp_id] = array(
                        
                            'price_pvp'       => $article->price_pvp,
                            'price_promotion' => $article->price_promotion,
                        
                    );

Comment: do you want it as a answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem with your code is your adding it in another array do this

> $prices_and_ids[$article->article_erp_id]

instead  of

> $prices_and_ids[]

```
foreach($resource->group->tabs as $tab) {
 foreach($tab->articles as $article) 
        {
            $prices_and_ids[$article->article_erp_id] = array(
                $article->article_erp_id => array(
                    'price_pvp'       => $article->price_pvp,
                    'price_promotion' => $article->price_promotion,
                )
            ); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $prices_and_ids[]   you should use $prices_and_ids[$article->article_erp_id]

```
foreach($resource->group->tabs as $tab) {

        foreach($tab->articles as $article) 
        {
            $prices_and_ids[$article->article_erp_id] array(
                    'price_pvp'       => $article->price_pvp,
                    'price_promotion' => $article->price_promotion,
                );

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach body as following code

```
$prices_and_ids[$article->article_erp_id] = array(
    'price_pvp'       => $article->price_pvp,
    'price_promotion' => $article->price_promotion,
);
```